# Joining sql queries - placeholder value missing in second query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically create and join sql queries depending on which search filters have been added to a search container.  Works OK with one filter, but when adding two filters, the placeholder (`_ORGAN_`) in one query isn't being replaced with the value of that filter element's value.

How should I change the code in the function for the search_btn to get this to work?

```
sql = [];
query = "SELECT * FROM specimen";
$('#system').change(function () {
    obj1 = {};
    obj1.filter = " topography_index = '_ORGAN_'";
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#system_menu_wrapper').prependTo('#search_container');
        sql.push(obj1);
    }
});

$('#keyword').change(function () {
    obj2 = {};
    obj2.filter = " MATCH(clinical_history) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(specimen) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(macroscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(microscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(conclusion) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(comment) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#keyword_field_wrapper').prependTo('#search_container');
        sql.push(obj2);
    }
});

$('#search_container').on('click', '#search_btn', function () {
    if ($("#search_container").find('#system_menu_wrapper').length) {
        var regExp1 = new RegExp('_ORGAN_', 'g');
        $.each(sql, function (index, value) {
            // store the replacement string as the .replaced property
            // so the .filter property remains unchanged and can be used
            // again in the future
            sql[index].replaced = sql[index].filter.replace(regExp1, 'T' + $('#organ_menu').val());
        });
    };

    if ($("#search_container").find('#keyword_field_wrapper').length) {
        var regExp2 = new RegExp('_KEYWORD_', 'g');
        $.each(sql, function (index, value) {
            // store the replacement string as the .replaced property
            // so the .filter property remains unchanged and can be used
            // again in the future
            sql[index].replaced = sql[index].filter.replace(regExp2, $('#keyword_field').val());
        });
    }

    if (sql.length) {
        var q = $.map(sql, function (elem) {
            return elem.replaced;
        });
        query += " WHERE " + q.join('  AND ');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'scripts/do_search.php',
        data: {
            query: query,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#search_results').html(data);
            $('#search_results').show();
            query = "SELECT * FROM specimen";
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hqS9/1/

Comment: You're storing the result of the replacement in `.replaced`. But the second loop is processing `.filter` instead of `.replaced`, so you're losing the results of the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the processing of the second field to:

```
if ($("#search_container").find('#keyword_field_wrapper').length) {
    var regExp2 = new RegExp('_KEYWORD_', 'g');
    var replacement = $('#keyword_field').val();
    $.each(sql, function (index, value) {
        // store the replacement string as the .replaced property
        // so the .filter property remains unchanged and can be used
        // again in the future
        value.replaced = (value.replaced || value.filter).replace(regExp2, replacement);
    });
}
```

This uses the `replaced` property as the input if it exists, otherwise the `filter` property, so that it builds on the replacements from the first loop.

Also, notice that you can use the `value` parameter of the iteration function rather than having to access `sql[index]` each time. And since `$('#keyword_field').val()` doesn't change during the loop, you should cache it in a variable outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks!  That works fine.  I'll need to add additional search elements so should I use this code for each of those?

Comment: Yes. All but the first one should be like this.

Comment: Actually changing the keyword field input (when used by itself) doesn't result in the keyword placeholder being updated with the new value...but it does when used in conjunction with the other search filter...

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle I'll see if I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: One problem: every time you change one of the filters it pushes onto `sql`, so you accumulate all the old filters instead of replacing them. You should have the `Search` button clear `sql` and then fill it in from all the inputs.

Comment: @Barmar...I think I have it sorted now, your answer was the basis of this, so I am marking it as correct.